# My laptop keeps crashing whenever I leave sleep mode

Tags: suspend, ssd, read-only, nvme

Whenever my laptop enters sleep mode and I want to use it again my system crashes after about 20 seconds.

When I enter my password and try using my system after leaving sleep mode I loose all of the icons of my files and system crashes soon after

[This is what happens before system crashes (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSpFe.jpg)

After that black screen appears and numerous EXT4-fs errors regarding my nvme ssd

[Here you can see black screen and errors that appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew5g9.jpg)

Here is the list of errors that appear:

```
EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p2): _ext4_find_entry:1663

systemd-journald[458]: Failed to write entry (23 items, 680 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
```

I tried to disable APST and put nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us = 0 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub but that didnt help

some more info about my system:

Im running Ubuntu 22.04
my ssd is KBG40ZNV512G KIOXIA 512GB Pcie nvme ssd
HP Laptop 15s-eq2079nm 434D3EA

thanks in advance!